# C , Xlib, can't get the name of focussed window

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xserver

This is the code I'm using,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

      Display *dpy;
      char *window_name_return = NULL;
      Window focused;
      int revert_to;

void main(){
    
    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL) ;
    if(!dpy) printf("error\n");
        
    XGetInputFocus(dpy, &focused, &revert_to);
    XFetchName(dpy, focused, &window_name_return);
    XFree(window_name_return);
    printf("Focus on %s\n", window_name_return);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
}
```

This works only for terminal emulator windows, for other window, the program returns, null.
The documentation for `XFetchName` says,

> If the WM_NAME property has not been set for this window, XFetchName()
> sets window_name_return to NULL

Is this why its not working? I use dwm window manager, running the code in Openbox did not work either.

How do I alter the code so that it works for all types of window?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The first is that you don't check the status returned by `XFetchName`;
- The second that you don't check if `window_name_return` is null or not;
- And the third and worst problem is that you free the string *before* you print it (making the pointer invalid).

Comment: Thank you for the information, I only attempted to learn Xlib yesterday and its been a very long time I used C.